# How to generate multiple rows in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to create a stored procedure that will accept multiple values in a parameter and return multiple rows.

This will be my parameters, having `classId` accept multiple values and insert multiple rows with same student name:

```
@studentName AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
@classId AS INTEGER = NULL
```

```
INSERT INTO studentClass (classId, studentName)
VALUES (@classId, @studentName)
```

Example John Doe is registered to class 1 and 2, I want to add Jane Doe to class 1 and 3. How do I do that in a single run?

```
classId | studentName
--------+------------
   1    | John Doe
   2    | John Doe
```

Run stored procedure with parameters:

```
@studentName = Jane Doe
@classId = 1,3
```

and will result into this

```
classId | studentName
--------+------------
   1    | John Doe
   2    | John Doe
   1    | Jane Doe
   3    | Jane Doe
```

Comment: Check out table valued parameters.

Comment: Or parameter as XML or JSON data type

Comment: try openxml or JSON as suggested by @YitzhakKhabinsky

Comment: @DaleK Do you know how I pass multiple values when executing stored procedure? Just like what J.D. Wrote he declared 
VALUES (1), (3);
Instead of this can I write like:
VALUES (@classIds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Dale mentioned in the comments, you can use [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) with [user-defined table types](https://sqlskull.com/2020/01/04/sql-server-user-defined-table-type-and-table-valued-parameters/) to create a parameter in your procedure that accepts a table of data at a time.

E.g. first:

```
-- Create user-defined table type
CREATE TYPE ClassIdsTable AS TABLE (ClassId INT);
```

Then:

```
-- Create procedure with table valued parameter
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertStudentClasses
    @StudentName NVARCHAR(255),
    @ClassIds ClassIdsTable
AS

-- Insert into studentClass table 
INSERT INTO studentClass (classId, studentName)
SELECT ClassId, @StudentName
FROM @ClassIds;

-- Return results from procedure 
SELECT ClassId, @StudentName
FROM @ClassIds;
```

Then you can call your procedure like so:

```
DECLARE @ClassIdsTable AS ClassIdsTable;
INSERT INTO @ClassIdsTable
VALUES (1), (3);

EXEC dbo.InsertStudentClasses 
    @StudentName = 'Jane Doe',
    @ClassIds = @ClassIdsTable;
```

---

Alternatively, if you're using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can also create the @ClassIds parameter as a string-based data type, and send in a comma delimited list of IDs instead. Then you can use the [`STRING_SPLIT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert it to a table of values. But it's a little anti-patternish to store multiple data points in a single string and has drawbacks.

Comment: I tried using what you wrote "@ClassIds ClassIdsTable" and shows "@ClassIds Invalid data type"

if ever I use the STRING_SPLIT() function, do I insert like this? VALUES (STRING_SPLIT(@classId,','), @studentName)

Comment: @ER_27 Did you create the type first?: `CREATE TYPE ClassIdsTable AS TABLE (ClassId INT);`

Comment: I got it, It only shows red underline but executed successfully.
What if I wanted to add another column? Do I create again another table type and add for example "BatchId INT" besides ClassId INT?

Comment: In the 'VALUES (1), (3);' can I pass values via Execute Stored Procedure? cause when I try to pass values 1,2,3 shows an error message: 'Must pass parameter number 3 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'.'

Comment: @ER_27 "*What if I wanted to add another column?*" - It's a table type, so you define as many columns as you want in it (just like a regular table) Instead of the original definition, you could do: `CREATE TYPE ClassIdsTable AS TABLE (ClassId INT, BatchId INT);`.

Comment: @ER_27 "*In the 'VALUES (1), (3);' can I pass values via Execute Stored Procedure?*" Yes, you you should be able to load the table variable with the results from a stores procedure but the structure of those results must match exactly to the structure of the table variable. Example code to do so would be: `INSERT INTO @ClassIdsTable EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProcedure`. I don't understand the error you described, please provide the lines of code you tried running.

Comment: So I added batchId column, it worked. when I insert values (1,112022),(3,092022) on the table shows classId with values 1,3 and batchId with 112022,092022. How do I make the input string look like this `(1,112022),(3,092022),(2,102022)` if the user will input on the stored procedure @classId '1,3,2' and on batchId '112022,092022,102022' ?

Comment: @ER_27 What do you mean by "*input string*'?

Comment: So basically from this input `@classId = 1,3,2` and `@batchId = 112022,092022,102022` into this `(1,112022),(3,092022),(2,102022)`

Comment: @ER_27 Oh, why do you have that input to begin with?...does that come from the application side (or how does it get created)? You should build out an `INSERT` statement already broken out like this: `INSERT INTO @ClassIdsTable
VALUES (1, 112022), (3, 092022), (2, 102022)`.